# How can I return an object from a method executed with RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I have a controller with Get, Save and Create actions. These actions take as a parameter an item type. This is just a string specifying what type of item we are processing.

There is a child controller for each of these item types, and each of these child controllers implement the child controller interface (IChildController) which has the Get, Save and Create methods.

Each child controller is named based on its type (ItemTypeController). When I'm getting an item from my parent controller, I can do it like this:

```
Get(string itemType, int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Get", itemType, new { id });
}
```

The Get method in the child controllers has an ActionResult return type (returns a Partival View) so this works without problem.

However, when I'm saving an item, all children are created and then returned to the parent object and stored within it so that a save can be performed on the parent only (and NHibernate will take care of cascading records).

How can I return objects from these methods without instantiating all the child controllers first. For example, I'd like to be able to call Save(itemType, item)

```
Save(string itemType, Item item)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Save", itemType, new { item });
}
```

and then we will find the appropriate child controller (itemTypeController), execute the method Save(item), and then return the item (item) back to the parent controller.

```
Save(Parent parent)
{
    IRepository<Parent> _parent;
    var item = new Parent();
    item.Id = parent.Id;
    item.Children = parent.Children.AddAll(parent.Children.Select(Save(parent.ChildType)); // save each child and add it to the parent's child collection
    return _parent.Save(item);
}

Save(Child child)
{
    IRepository<Child> _child;
    var item = new Child();
    item.Id = child.Id;
    return _child.Save(item);
}
```

What is the best solution to achieve this? Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

How would I go about converting complex objects into ViewModels. For example, a Parent object that contains children of type Child.

In the ParentTypeController we have:

```
ParentViewModel ToViewModel(Parent parent)
{
    var model = new ParentViewModel();
    model.Id = parent.Id;
    model.Children = parent.Children.Select(ToViewModel); //Use the ToViewModel method in the ChildTypeController
    return model;
}
```

ChildTypeController:

```
ChildViewModel ToViewModel(Child child)
{
    var model = new ChildViewModel();
    model.Id = child.Id;
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Your initial question asked one thing, and your edit asks an entirely different question.  These should be separate.

Comment: @bfir3: Did you manage to get it working? Can you approve one of the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should **not** be using `RedirectToAction()` as a general pattern the way you are.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx):

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser
>   to make a GET request to the specified action.

So for every single request a user makes of your application, you're forcing them to actually make **two**!  If you want to use overloaded methods you can do so within your controller; you don't need to cause a browser redirect.

I think once you free yourself of that pattern the rest will emerge naturally.  In my own projects I've found that it's often best to perform database actions in two steps - (1) create or update, followed by (2) request a "fresh" object state from the database again.

Answer (score 0):

Think you have a problem defining the right abstraction. Don't use controllers for this kind of behavior or interactions. You already have a repository, so let it do the heavy lifting.

You shouldn't call actions from actions, unless there is a really good reason for it. An http requests maps to an (functional) action. An action can use the model (in Mvc) and use the return value to create the response.

Not sure why you want or need this parent/child hierarchy in your controller. Maybe you can explain why you need it.

**Edit**
Try [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) "A convention-based object-object mapper in .NET." to convert object graphs into other object graphs. Works great for simple and complex conversions.